# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, pdo, doctrine-orm

This error to me seems a bug because there are no positional parameters in my query. Here is the method:

```
public function getAll(User $user, DateTime $start = null, DateTime $end = null)
{
    $params = array('user_id' => $user->getId());

    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping(); // Result set mapping
    $rsm->addScalarResult('subtype', 'subtype');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('count',   'count');

    $sms_sql =
    "SELECT CONCAT('sms_', IF(is_auto = 0, 'user' , 'auto')) AS subtype, " .
    "SUM(messages_count * (customers_count + recipients_count)) AS count " .
    "FROM outgoing_message AS m INNER JOIN small_text_message AS s ON " . 
    "m.id = s.id WHERE status <> 'pending' AND user_id = :user_id";

    $news_sql =
    "SELECT CONCAT('news_', IF(is_auto = 0, 'user' , 'auto')) AS subtype, " .
    "SUM(customers_count + recipients_count) AS count " .
    "FROM outgoing_message AS m JOIN newsletter AS n ON m.id = n.id " .
    "WHERE status <> 'pending' AND user_id = :user_id";

    if($start) :
        $sms_sql        .= " AND sent_at >= :start";
        $news_sql       .= " AND sent_at >= :start";
        $params['start'] = $start->format('Y-m-d');
    endif;

    $sms_sql  .= ' GROUP BY type, is_auto';
    $news_sql .= ' GROUP BY type, is_auto';

    return $this->_em->createNativeQuery("$sms_sql UNION ALL $news_sql", $rsm)
        >setParameters($params)->getResult();
}
```

And this throws the exception:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional
>   parameters

Array `$params` is OK and so [generated SQL](http://pastebin.com/Rx0BQsV6):

```
var_dump($params);

array (size=2)
  'user_id' => int 1
  'start' => string '2012-01-01' (length=10)
```

The strangest thing is that it works with `"$sms_sql"` only!

## Update

Found another strange thing. If I change only the name (to `start_date` instead of `start`):

```
    if($start) :
        $sms_sql             .= " AND sent_at >= :start_date";
        $news_sql            .= " AND sent_at >= :start_date";
        $params['start_date'] = $start->format('Y-m-d');
    endif;
```

What happens is that Doctrine/PDO says:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sent1rt_date'
>   in 'where clause'

... as string `1rt` was added in the middle of the column name!

Comment: This line is wear,"SUM(messages_count * (customers_count + recipients_count)) AS count " can you open your mysql command line and test the only the query?

Comment: @jcho360 that line works fine as i said if i use only $sms_sql as query it works!

Comment: There's oddities in your SQL, but I don't think it's the problem. The references to the status, user_id, sent_at, is_auto and type columns aren't qualifeid with a table alias. You are using the reserved word "count" as an alias in the SELECT list (it should really be enclosed in backticks). It's a bit odd that you are grouping by 'type' but that column isn't included anywhere else in the query. It's legal, just a bit odd. I'd qualify it with a table alias. But none of that is really the problem.

Comment: I don't see a problem here, if your ORM is using named parameters, UNLESS it can only map a named parameter to one position. (That would be odd.) One thing I would try is naming each of the four parameters  unique, and passing in an array of four, and test that.

Comment: @spencer7593 look at my edits (changing the parameter name). It seems working using only positional parameters, but i have to investigate further. I'm going to look also for your suggestions about the query oddities.

Comment: @spencer7593 guess what... as you said, Doctrine seems not supporting binding the same parameter with the same name. So using user_id1, user_id2, start_date1 and start_date2 seems working. I'm going to test it a bit more and then you can answer (maybe with a reference to Doctrine documentation) to this question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Gremo. I didn't find any examples that show using the setParameters method for named parameters. All of the named parameter examples only showed a named parameter being bound to a single placeholder in the statement. And so it goes for NativeSql support...

Comment: @spencer7593 well write an answer anyway, i'll accept it. Maybe other people can solve this in future (not spending hours like me)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the Doctrine ORM support for NativeSQL.

I don't find any examples in the documentation of the `setParameters` method being used for named parameters. All of the examples I see of that method being used are for positional, rather than named.

All of the examples for named parameters use the `setParameter` (with no "s") method. And they only show a single occurrence of a matching placeholder in the SQL.

As a test (and as a possible workaround), try making each placeholder in the SQL text unique, and then set each one separately.

It looks like "named parameter" support may be somewhat incomplete (compared to what we are used to with Oracle and other ORM frameworks). It looks like Doctrine may have better support for the positional notation.  (Which is great for simple statements, but it can be a real bear when you have lots of parameters, and you need to make changes to a SQL statement. That's where the benefit of named parameters really begins to shine... if they are supported right.)

Here's a link to the Doctrine ORM documentation [*http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html?highlight=setParameters*](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html?highlight=setParameters)  (Search for `setParameters` on that page for examples.)

(See my comments on your question.)

That may not really answer your question, but it may get you moving in the right direction. Be careful out there.